# dplyr package: the sentence of "compare %>% summarise(p.value = aov$`Pr(>F)`)" don't work

Tags: r, dplyr

The example of do() function in dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
by_cyl <- group_by(mtcars, cyl)
models <- by_cyl %>% do(
  mod_linear = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .),
  mod_quad = lm(mpg ~ poly(disp, 2), data = .)
)
models
compare <- models %>% do(aov = anova(.$mod_linear, .$mod_quad))
compare %>% summarise(p.value = aov$`Pr(>F)`)
```

The last sentence don't work, and generate a error: expecting a single value.
I don't konw why it happen, and thanks for someone telling me.

Comment: Try `compare %>% summarise(P.value=aov[[6]][2])` or `compare %>% summarise(P.value=aov[['Pr(>F)']][2])`

Comment: Thank you, the codes provided by you work very well. And then another question is that why it goes wrong in my codes?

Comment: I understand that this code is from the help `?do`, but it is possible that the example worked for an earlier version of `dplyr` and no longer works.  Anyway, I would prefer to use `[` than `$`